Suggestions on the guidelines on the proper uses of the tag `glyph-origin` and `etymology`
Thanks to all moderators/high-rep persons involved in reviewing the question edits under the original etymology tag. Hopefully, this tag and glyph-origin, and their descriptions, are now compatible with the fields of linguistics and paleography.
I'd like to suggest that we have a list of guidelines on the proper use of glyph-origin and etymology for existing and new members, as there is still potential confusion between the two. Indeed, many questions here on Chinese SE require both tags to get a fully comprehensive answer, but many questions are solely on character or character-component history, and have little to do with etymology. This is especially true of characters which are classified as rebus (假借).
From the above, since the tags overlap in a few areas, my proposal is to describe what the tags shouldn't be used for:

glyph-origin should not be used for the following, unless the question also asks about the graphical evolution:

The origin of words from phonetic loans
Foreign loanwords
Words composed of two or more characters, unless the question is asking about the glyph origin of at least one of the characters as it serves as a significant semantic indicator of the word as a whole.

etymology should not be used for the following, unless the question also asks about the spoken word:

Ideographs (指示)/Compound Ideographs (會意)/Pictographs (象形)
Character components (e.g. this and this)


Of course, all this is based on how well the question was researched before asked.
Any suggestions/improvements/totally new guides?

Looking good. Very nice.
